# How to make non-English letters readable in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
d = {}
with open('transl.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:  
        (key, val) = line.split(' = ')
        d[key] = val

print d
```

Here is what\s in **transl.txt(coding is ANSI)** file:

```
send = button
addr = аддрес
```

When I run my program I get this output:

```
'addr': '\xe0\xe4\xe4\xf0\xe5\xf1', 'send': 'button\n'
```

Comment: Likely it's windows-1251 encoding.

Comment: BTW, in Russian the word `адрес` has single `д` and single `с` :)

Comment: технарям не положено знать язык

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
d = {}
with open('transl.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:  
        (key, val) = line.split(' = ')
        d[key] = val.decode("windows-1251")
# now the values contain unicode strings.
# this may or may not be desired. If you need to convert them
# back to byte sequences in a given encoding use `.encode(<encoding-name>)`
# method of unicode string
print d
```

Comment: anyway, I don't get what I need: I get this:'\xef\xbb\xbfsend': u'button\n', 'addr': u'\u0420\xb0\u0420\u0491\u0420\u0491\u0421\u0402\u0420\xb5\u0421\u0403' instead of this ['send': 'button', 'addr': 'аддрес']

Comment: `print(d)` will always print escaped data, because it uses `repr()`. You may try to `print(d['addr'])` and see what happens. If the console is configured properly you'll get correct output.

Comment: Thank you, a kind man, who knows how to write the Russian word 'адрес' correctly. Now it works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) from the standard library.

```
import codecs
d = {}
with codecs.open('transl.txt', encoding='maccyrillic') as f:
    for line in f:  
        (key, val) = line.split(u' = ')
        d[key] = val
print d['button']
```

You can find a [list of standard codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) in the documentation.
Your input looks like it's [`maccyrillic`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Cyrillic_encoding).

Comment: anyway, I don't get what I need: I get this:'\xef\xbb\xbfsend': u'button\n', 'addr': u'\u0420\xb0\u0420\u0491\u0420\u0491\u0421\u0402\u0420\xb5\u0421\u0403' instead of this ['send': 'button', 'addr': 'аддрес']

Comment: You have to find the correct encoding. I think it's [macintosh cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Cyrillic_encoding), which gives me `u'\u0430\u0434\u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441'` which is the same as аддрес

Answer (score -1):

It must be your terminal that isn't configured properly; set the LANG and LC_ALL environment variables to en_US.UTF-8 or your language's unicode equivalent.